# FastApi base model error while trying to query a Mongodb database

Tags: python, mongodb, fastapi

```py
from pymongo import MongoClient
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from bson import ObjectId
# pip install pymongo
# pip install fastapi
# pip install uvicorn
# pip install python-multipart


# MongoDB connection
username = "root"
password = "root"
client = MongoClient(f"mongodb://{username}:{password}@localhost:27017")
db = client.companies
companies = db.companies



# class company for the companies table
class Company(BaseModel):
    name: str
    field: str
    manager: str
    phone: str

# company class to dict for the get method
def company_dict(company) -> dict:
    return {
        "id": str(company["_id"]),
        "name": company["name"],
        "field": company["field"],
        "manager": company["manager"],
        "phone": company["phone"]
    }

# makes a list of dictionaries of comapnies from a collection of Company class
def list_of_companies(companies):
    return [company_dict(company) for company in companies]



app = FastAPI()
# company post method -> adds a company of type Comapny
@app.post('/')
def post_companies(company: Company):
    companies.insert_one(dict(company))
# company get method -> returns all of the companies
@app.get('/')
def get_companies():
    return list_of_companies(companies.find())
# company get method -> returns a specific company that matches the company name given
@app.get('/{name}')
def get_a_company(name: str):
    return company_dict(companies.find_one({"name": name}))

@app.get('/{field}')
def get_all_companies_of_a_field(field: str):
    return list_of_companies(companies.find({"field": {"$eq": field}}))
```

thats the code and the error is

```
return company_dict(companies.find_one({"name": name}))
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\MongoDB_FastApi\mongoconn.py", line 30, in company_dict
    "id": str(company["_id"]),
              ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

I had the first 3 queries and used them with no problem and when I'm trying to add another query like the forth one it always ends with the same TypeError, any suggestions?

Comment: if the value is empty, which is probably is, then the code will throw this error.

Comment: the get method shows that every value is not empty but specifically when I'm doing a different get method of more than one company with a filter it returns an error

Comment: i can not see the `get()` method that you refer to, but i could reproduce a similar error with a dataclass example. And leave the `name=None`.

Comment: i could also produce this error by passing a list into the `name=` paramater. did you do this ?

Comment: `find_one` returns None, which you then attempt to use as a dictionary. The company you're querying for by `name` doesn't exist, or `name` is unquerable (I'm not familiar which conditions cause `find_one` to return None, but it seems like you're assuming that a company will always be found.